# Intellij not going to line number of error when I click on the error message

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I'm running a flask app inside of intellij, and when there's an error the stacktrace has the line number, but clicking on the error doesn't take me to the line, it just takes me to the top of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: This like looks like a link ? It has blue color ?

Comment: Yeah it's got a link, but it doesn't take me to the line number just the top of the file.

Comment: Seems its a bug with Flask under IntelliJ